# Not able to communicate between keycloak and gatekeeper

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I am totally a newbie in key-cloak and keycloak-gatekeeper
I am running keycloak on my machine with address localhost:8080 where as my gatekeeper is running on minikube environment
Below are the my configuration and deployment file

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gatekeeperdeployment
  labels:
    app: gatekeeperapp
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: gatekeeperapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gatekeeperapp
    spec: 
      containers: 
      - image: keycloak/keycloak-gatekeeper:7.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: gatekeeperalone
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
        args:
        - --config=/etc/secrets/config.yml
        - --redirection-url=http://127.0.0.1:3000
        - --upstream-url=http://192.168.99.101:30732
        - --resources=uri=/prods
        - --enable-logging=true
        - --enable-json-logging=true
        - --verbose=true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: secret
          mountPath: /etc/secrets
      volumes:
      - name: secret
        secret:
          secretName: secret-gatekeeper
```

and my config file is as:

```
client-id: ems
client-secret: 17a9da01-880a-432c-ba5a-8cbf131d5634
discovery-url: http://127.0.0.1:8180/auth/realms/ems_realm
redirection-url: http://127.0.0.1:3000
upstream-url: http://192.168.99.101:30732
skip-upstream-tls-verify: true
skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
encryption-key: 1234567898765431
listen: 3000
secure-cookie: false
enable-logging: true
enable-json-logging: true
enable-default-deny: true
enable-refresh-tokens: true
enable-session-cookies: true
debug: true
ingress.enabled: true
resources:
  - uri: /prods
```

i have set the localhost path in discovery-url parameter.

So, with above configuration i am not able to communicate with the keycloak. Please provide some guidance over this behaviour. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that Keycloak is running on the 127.0.0.1:8180 (discovery-url) in the gatekeeper container? Containers are running in the own network namespaces, so localhost in the container is different as localhost in the OS. Configure that discovery-url correctly or configure used network namespace of the host (e.g. use host network if keycloak is running in the host network).